# Invalid Syntax in Countdown and Factorial

Tags: python, countdown, factorial

I'm new to Python and programming in general, and I can't figure out what I'm entering incorrectly.

I am attempting to create a "Countdown and Factorial" program that allows my user to input a number that will be used as either a countdown or factorial depending on the second input entry of a `1` or `2`.

If they choose `1`, then the program will run a countdown of `num`.  If they choose `2` then it will run a factorial of `num`.

I believe that I have created a proper script but, every time I try to run the program in IDLE, I get an "Invalid Syntax" popup at line 13/14. Line 13 is the blank line between the two `input` lines.

Could anyone please help me figure out why I am getting this syntax error popup? The code is below:

```
import math

def countdown():
    if num == 0:
        return
    print(num)
    countdown(num-1)

def factorial():
    print(math.factorial(num))

num = int(input('Please enter an integer greater than 1.\n')

userChoice = int(input('Please enter a either 1 or 2. If 1 is entered, a countdown from that number to zero is printed. If 2 is entered, the factorial of the number is printed.\n'))

if userChoice == '1':
    countdown()
elif userChoice == '2':
    factorial()
```

Comment: You should post your code as text, *not* an external image. In any case, you are missing a closing `)` on your `num = int(input(...` line. I'd suggest you make sure your *next* question is self-contained :-)

Comment: Paxdiablo I greatly appreciate your keen eye! I was so confused and frustrated! Now just to get the rest of the code to work and I'm all set.  Thanks again!

Comment: No probs, Hydreaux. As an aside, you can just copy your code into the question, highlight it, then use CTRL-K to indent it by 4 spaces. This tells SO to render as a code block.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that tip paxdiablo!!

Comment: Hydreaux, I've converted your image into text since that's more acceptable here.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies on this line:

```
num = int(input('Please enter an integer greater than 1.\n')
#        ^_____^                                       ____^___
#        open(2)                                       close(1)
```

You have two opening parentheses but only one *closing* one. It should be:

```
num = int(input('Please enter an integer greater than 1.\n'))
#                                                          _^_
#                                                          add
```